# Ctrl+; doesn't insert current date in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: shortcut-keys, libreoffice, 22.04

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 (normal install on hardware) soon after it was released. It came with LibreOffice 7.3.2.2.

The problem is that the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> doesn't insert the current date into a cell anymore. Instead, it enters an underlined "e", which turns out to be a starting point for inserting emojis. If you enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> then press <kbd>Space</kbd>, up pops a menu showing different categories of emojis:

[image: emoji pop-up]

The menu *Insert* → *Date*, still shows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> to be the keyboard shortcut, but something is clearly wrong.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> does insert the current time as it should.

Is this fixable, or a LibreOffice bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>semicolon</kbd> is defined as an emoji shortcut in `ibus-setup`, tab *Emoji*.
You may remove it, or try <kbd>LeftCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>semicolon</kbd> to insert a date.

Comment: Thank you kindly. I removed it. Both Left and Right Ctrl+; were inserting the emoji prompt, but your solution worked nicely.

Comment: Yes,  LeftCtrl+; do not enter emoji only through VNC

Comment: THANK YOU. That fixed it. I would point out for those not sure, that ibus preferences can be found under the KDE Menu | Settings.

Comment: I have the same problem but removing the "emoji shortcut in ibus-setup, tab Emoji" did not solve the problem - I used the terminal with command "ibus-setup" to get there - - I have no idea what the "KDE Menu" is. Do you perhaps have any idea how I should proceed? Thank you for your time and help and expertise.